# Copy text from textbox on one form to label on another form

Tags: c#

My application has a textbox and a label on different forms. I want to copy textbox text to the label.

I tried the following code:

```cs
//creating the variable
string vInput = textbox1.Text;

//set label text on the other form
label1.Text = vInput
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: How are the two forms related?  Are you sure that it's actually 2 *forms*?  Your code looks like you're trying to access 2 *controls* on 1 form.  Can you clarify?

Comment: We don't know what “it just said that vInput didn't work” means. If you're getting an error message you need to [add the message to your question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, if I'm understanding you correctly. To access a variable from another class, you either need to pass it as a parameter or make it a class property. Broots Waymb's [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042303/accessing-variables-in-other-windows-form-class) link explains class properties.

To pass as a parameter would look something like this.

```
public class Form2 {
   //Form2 class constructor
   public Form2(string vInputFromForm1) {
      //your code using passed in string
   }
}

public class Form1 {
   //...
   public void someMethod() {
      string vInput = textbox1.Text;
      Form2 form2 = new Form2(vInput); 
   }
}
```

If neither of these options solves your problem, you may want to edit your question to add more information. As Dour High Arch mentioned, providing error messages can go a long way towards understanding the problem in the first place.

Comment: this is the error message that i got :      Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0103 The name 'vInput' does not exist in the current context